# What's the point of oEmbed API endpoints and URL schemes vs. link tags?

Tags: html, standards, oembed

The [oEmbed](http://oembed.com) specification mentions 2 different ways of finding the oEmbed content of an URL:

1. Knowing the API endpoint of the website and passing it, through a GET parameter, the URL you want info about, if it matches the URL pattern it declared.
2. Discovering the URL of the oEmbed version thanks to a `<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" ... />` (or `text/xml+oembed`) HTML header.

The 2nd ways seems more generic, as you don't have to store and maintain a whole list of providers. Moreover, lists of providers are the sign of a centralized internet, where only a few actors exist. This approach is hardly scalable.

I can see a use for the 1st approach, though, for websites that can parse resources made available by someone else. For example, I can provide an oEmbed version of video pages from website Foo. However, for several reasons, mainly security-related, I wouldn't trust someone who says "I can parse resource X for you" unless X's author is OK with that, which brings us back to approach 2.

So my question is: what did I miss here? What's the use of the 1st method of dealing with oEmbed? For instance, why store (and maintain up-to-date) a whole list of endpoints and patterns [like oohEmbed does](http://code.google.com/p/oohembed/source/browse/app/provider/endpoints.json) if you have a generic way of discovering it on-the-fly and for virtually any resource on the internet?

As a very closely related question, which I think may be asked at the same time (please correct me if I'm wrong): what happens if one doesn't provide a central endpoint for oEmbed contents, but rather, say, expect a '?version=oembed' parameter on each URL, that returns the oEmbed version instead of the standard one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, supporting both mechanisms was a compromise that we figured would help drive adoption. It's much easier to persuade large web properties to add a single endpoint vs. adding markup (that's irrelevant to most clients) to every response body. It was a pragmatic choice.

Longer term we planned to leverage some of the work Eran Hammer-Lahav was doing around discovery rather than re-inventing it (poorly, again). Unfortunately, his ideas still haven't gotten much traction and the web still lacks a good, standardized way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping to find an answer here but it looks like everyone else is as confused as we are. The advantage of using option 1 in my opinion is that it only uses 1 json request instead of a potentially expensive html request followed by the json request. You can always use option 2 as a fallback in case you can't match a pattern in your pre-baked list of oEmbed providers.

Answer (score -1):

OEmbed discovery is a major security concern. WordPress for example has a whitelist of supported OEmbed providers.

Suppose that every random URL at the internet can trigger an OEmbed code. That means everyone can hack your site.

Steps:

1. Create a new site, add an OEmbed discovery.
2. Post the URL to a form at your site. Now your site perform the OEmbed on my behalf.
3. Exploit:

   - by denial-of-service (DOS): e.g. redirect the URL to a tarpit or feed it a 1GB json response.
   - by cross site scripting (XSS): inject random HTML to pages that other people can see.
   - by stealing the admin's session-cookie via XSS: now the attacker can login to your CMS to upload files, and exploit even more.

It's XSS to the max, with little to stop it. The only sane thing to do, is whitelisting proper endpoints. That's the oEmbed endpoints are explicitly listed.

If you want something scalable, you might like www.noembed.com and www.embedly.com They provide OEmbed support for various sites which don't do OEmbed themselves.

Comment: If I'm interpreting it property and you're concerned about DDoS attacks, you can do all of that without oEmbed. There's no extra vulnerability I can see because of it.

As for XSS attacks, yes, that's why if you're allowing random internet content to be embedded on your site you host it on an iframe using a different domain (and preferably cleanse it of scripts as well). That goes for content from YouTube as well as some random site. You never trust third party content, regardless if the source is well known or not.